# Will the Vibrate Permission filter an app from Google TV in the Android Market?

Tags: android, permissions, android-manifest, television

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"></uses-permission>
```

Will an app requiring this show up in the Android Market for Google TV?

Comment: probably the remote would vibrate;-)

Comment: I dunno, maybe the screen will shake. I'm trying to ensure my app will work on as many Android devices as possible. I read [this](https://developers.google.com/tv/android/docs/gtv_market_filtering), but didn't see anything specifically about hardware features. .

Comment: I suggested to Google that Google TV devices be outfitted with a USB attachment that would vibrate the user's sofa. The response was "contributions are welcome"... :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That permission will not block an app from showing up in the Market for Google TV devices.

The only permissions that are at risk of blocking an app from showing up in the Market are [those that imply a hardware feature that is covered by `<uses-feature>`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html#permissions). There is no `<uses-feature>` for the vibration motor. Hence, the `VIBRATE` permission does not imply any particular `<uses-feature>` element.